# How to edit AWS CloudFront setting to edit origin and origin group settings using terraform

Tags: terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am particularly looking for way to have the following settings as shown in the image bellow. I want to make the S3 bucket restricted and choose to create new origin access identity as shown bellow.

Also it should make the update in S3 bucket policy, the settings might look different in image though.

In nutshell, I could not find or may be I didn't understand the official terraform documentations for achieving it. 
[image: CloudFront settings for origin and origin groups]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below one for the reference,

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "www" {
  origin {
    domain_name = "${var.bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com"
    origin_id   = "wwwS3Origin"

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = "${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.cloudfront_access_identity_path}"
    }
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  comment             = "Some comment"
  default_root_object = "index.html"

......

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "origin_access_identity" {
  comment = "S3 bucket OAI"
}
```

Update bucket policy

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_policy" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.example.arn}/*"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.iam_arn}"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:ListBucket"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.example.arn}"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.iam_arn}"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "example" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.example.id}"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_policy.json}"
}
```

Refer the below link for more details

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudfront_origin_access_identity.html#updating-your-bucket-policy

Comment: I have tried it and it just adds the bucket policy and I don't get the settings shown in the image letting me in the same issue.

Comment: Can u post the screenshot of the console?

Comment: Thanks Abhinaya, For now I rather choose to use someone else module and add my requirements. Cloudposse  have great collections of modules